# Шарики отталкиваются от стен и друг друга

Tags: delphi, анимация, графика, graphics

Нужна помощь с программой, где несколько шариков отталкиваются от стен и бьются друг об друга. 
Вот код, где один шар летает по форме и отталкивается от стен.

```
var      
Form1: TForm1;
PosX, Posy, VelX, Vely: single;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Posx:=3;
  PosY:=5;
  VelX:=2;
  VelY:=2;
end;

procedure TForm1.shar;
begin
  PosX:= PosX+VelX;
  PosY:= PosY+VelY;
  if PosX > ClientWidth - Shp1.Width then
  begin
    PosX:= ClientWidth - Shp1.Width;
    VelX:= - VelX;
  end
  else
  if PosX < 0 then
  begin
    PosX:= 0;
    VelX:= -VelX;
  end;
  if PosY > ClientHeight - Shp1.Width then
  begin
    POsY:= ClientHeight - Shp1.Width;
    VelY:= - VelY;
  end
  else
  if PosY < 0 then
  begin
    POsY:= 0;
    VelY:= - VelY;
  end;
  Shp1.Left:= Round(PosX);
  Shp1.Top:= Round(PosY);
end;

procedure TForm1.tmr1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  shar;
end;

end.
```

Не могу разобраться как добавить еще шариков и сделать, чтоб они отталкивались друг от друга. Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Не знаю, на сколько delphi объектный язык, но из элементарных решений - сделай массивы(коллекции) переменных `PosX, Posy, VelX, Vely` и так же ассоциируй их с графикой. При каждом проходе еще добавить сравнение координат м/у собой и их инверсию при условии.

Comment: переписывал я когда то заставку _Мыльные пузыри_ не делфях с директ2д, И понял что программировать физику столкновений шаров явно не мое :)

Comment: Сделал массивы переменных и теперь могу добавлять любое количество шаров. Но вот с отталкиванием друг от друга проблема..

Comment: @NikkiBAN ну так нужно проверять теперь весь массив, столкнулся шарик с другим или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шарики, их скорости и координаты занес в массивы. Размеры всех шариков одинаковые.

```
procedure bumpWalls; //столкновение со стенами
var
i: Cardinal;
begin
with Form1 do
begin
for i := 0 to BallCount - 1 do
begin
  masPosX[i] := masPosX[i] + masVelX[i]; 
  masPosY[i] := masPosY[i] + masVelY[i]; 

  if masPosX[i] > ClientWidth - Shp1.Width then
  begin
    masPosX[i] := ClientWidth - Shp1.Width;
    masVelX[i] := -masVelX[i];
  end
  else if masPosX[i] < 0 then
  begin
    masPosX[i] := 0;
    masVelX[i] := -masVelX[i];
  end;
  if masPosY[i] > ClientHeight - Shp1.Width then
  begin
    masPosY[i] := ClientHeight - Shp1.Width;
    masVelY[i] := -masVelY[i];
  end
  else if masPosY[i] < 0 then
  begin
    masPosY[i] := 0;
    masVelY[i] := -masVelY[i];
  end;
end;
end;
end;

procedure bumpEachOther;  //столкновение друг с другом
var
h0, h1, i, j: Cardinal;
a, b, dist, bet, x1, x2, y1, y2: extended;
n: integer;
xx0, yy0, xx1, yy1: single;
begin
for i := 1 to 10 do  
begin
for h0 := 0 to ballcount - 1 do
begin
  for h1 := 0 to ballcount - 1 do
    if h0 <> h1 then
    begin
      a := MasPosX[h0] + MasVelX[h0] * 0.001 - MasPosX[h1] - MasVelX[h1] * 0.001;
      b := MasPosY[h0] + MasVelY[h0] * 0.001 - MasPosY[h1] - MasVelY[h1] * 0.001;
      dist := sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b));
      if dist <= 241 then
      begin
        bet := arctan2(MasPosY[h1] - MasPosY[h0], MasPosX[h1] - MasPosX[h0]); 
        x1 := masvelx[h0] * cos(-bet) - MasVelY[h0] * sin(-bet);
        y1 := MasVelX[h0] * sin(-bet) + MasVelY[h0] * cos(-bet);
        x2 := MasVelX[h1] * cos(-bet) - MasVelY[h1] * sin(-bet);
        y2 := MasVelX[h1] * sin(-bet) + MasVelY[h1] * cos(-bet);
        MasVelX[h0] := x2 * cos(bet) - y1 * sin(bet);
        MasVelY[h0] := x2 * sin(bet) + y1 * cos(bet);
        masVelX[h1] := x1 * cos(bet) - y2 * sin(bet);
        MasVelY[h1] := x1 * sin(bet) + y2 * cos(bet);
        n := 0;
        xx0 := masvelx[h0];
        yy0 := masvely[h0];
        xx1 := masvelx[h1];
        yy1 := masvely[h1];
        repeat  
          MasPosX[h0] := MasPosX[h0] + xx0 * 0.0011;
          MasPosY[h0] := MasPosY[h0] + yy0 * 0.0011;
          MasPosX[h1] := MasPosX[h1] + xx1 * 0.0011;
          MasPosY[h1] := MasPosY[h1] + yy1 * 0.0011;
          a := MasPosX[h0] - MasPosX[h1];
          b := MasPosY[h0] - MasPosY[h1];
          dist := sqrt(sqr(a) + sqr(b));
          inc(n);
        until (dist > 241) or (n > 50000);

      end;
    end;

  MasPosX[h0] := MasPosX[h0] + MasVelX[h0] * 0.001;
  MasPosY[h0] := MasPosY[h0] + MasVelY[h0] * 0.001;
end;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Нужно использовать преимущества ООП и правильно спроектировать классы.
Не знаю как именно называется паттерн (ну может кто есть из фанатов Кэнта Бэка, знает название).
Для начала нужен класс управляющий шарами.
`TSharManager` у него должны быть свойства инициализации объектов (`InitObjects`) и их изменение в пространстве при столкновении, ну и прорисовки соответственно (`DrawObjects`).
А также в этом классе нужно задать характеристики стен. 
Сам класс `TShar` должен содержать информацию о шаре.
Хранить все в отдельных переменных прямой путь к тотальной путанице и сложнейшей отладке.
У класса `TShar` должны быть свойства `Radius`, `LeftCentrPos`, `TopCentrPos` , `Color` (ну может для этой задачи это и не нужно, но добавить легко), `Plotnost` (можно пренебречь физикой, но если будет необходимость, то тоже легко добавить) и главное вектор и скорость движения. (Можно скорость движения по Х и по Y)
Сразу скажу, что физическую формулу сложения сил в момент столкновения я не помню. 
Но в её результате эти свойства должны поменяться. То есть будет метод в котором пересчитываются координаты двух столкнувшихся объектов. Понять то, что они столкнутся можно по тому, что сумма радиусов будет равна расстоянию между центрами. В отличии от квадрата/прямоугольника здесь столкновение идет не в тот момент, когда соприкасаются границы. На основе характеристик шаров рассчитываем новую траекторию (вектор и скорость). Теоретически может и несколько шаров столкнутся одновременно.Но это уже следующий шаг. Упростим ,что сталкиваются только два шара. Нужно перебрать все шары и выяснить соприкасаются ли радиусы. А также выяснить соприкоснется ли шар со стеной. В обоих случаях меняется направление движения и его вектор. 
Не знаю насколько помог, но алгоритм думаю должен быть таким.. Тут больше математики и физики. Задача достаточно объемная, чтобы писать тут код и составлять модель.

Comment: +1, но наличие паттерна и классов тут вовсе не обязательно. Ядро решения лежит в переборе пар сближающихся шаров. А уж в чем они лежат и кем "проверяются" - дело десятое.